# redirect after authentication is successful

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authentication

When the user clicks on the paybill (secure page) option, he/she is prompted to log-in & then be redirected to the account page. I am using `Page.ResolveUrl` in the `Login_Authenticate` method. Once logged in, if the user navigates to any different page on the website & then clicks on paybill again, I check the `Identity.IsAuthenticated` status in the page load and depending on this I again redirect the user to the account page. I want to know if this is the right way or if there are any best practices for doing this as this involves a lot of server calls. Can I do this functionality using the `LoggedInTemplate` in the `asp:LoginView` or Javascript? I have the code for your ref...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //to directly link user to account if it's authenticated
    var userauth = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    if (userauth)
    {
        string urlredirect = Page.ResolveUrl("~/" + SiteConfig.PageMappings["ACCOUNT"]);
        Response.Redirect(urlredirect);
        Server.TransferRequest(urlredirect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do both the Redirect and the TransferRequest.  Response.Redirect sends a 302 to the browser to tell it to access a new page.  Server.TransferRequest causes the request to be handled in a different Page within the existing request.  If you're doing authentication, you likely want to scrap the current session and start over, which means just using Response.Redirect.  I use Response.Redirect in circumstances like this.  I also think it's useful for the user to see they've been redirected to another page for login (as well as being useful for page caching and back/forth navigation in the browser. w.r.t to authentication and login).